# Oracle SQL - trying to find values that exist for one section and not in the other using the same column

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry for the potentially simple question - but i am very new to sql.

Basically - I have a table where I need to check where certain values do not exist in the next set.

I have 3 columns - lets call them year,name, and col3 which is not relevant.
Now I need to see which names exist in 2009 but not in 2010 and all following years?
I am absolutely clueless as to how this works.

What I have is:

```
select *
from table1
where year > 2008 and year < 2012
```

and then I am not sure how to place another query in there? I am thinking something like:

```
select * 
table1
```

where the name not equal to name in previous year?

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This is "set-within-sets" query.  The "set" is all rows for name.  The "within-sets" is that the year "2009" is present, but the others are not.

My preferred way to solve this is with `group by` and `having`, because this is the most general formulation.  Here is how it works for your query:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having sum(case when year = 2009 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when year > 2009 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The expression `sum(case when year = 2009 then 1 else 0 end)` counts the number of rows with 2009 for a given name.  The name "passes" only when there is at least one row (`> 0`).  The second condition counts the number of rows with a year larger than 2009.  A name passes when there are none of those `= 0`.

EDIT:

The reason I prefer this method is because of flexibility.  For instance, if you wanted 2009 and 2010, the query would be:

```
having sum(case when year = 2009 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when year = 2010 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you wanted 2009, 2010, and not 2011:

```
having sum(case when year = 2009 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when year = 2010 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when year = 2011 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

All of these have essentially the same run-time.

Comment: Gordon, i see that your query will also do the job, for my learning can you throw light on how it would compare against the more simpler alternatives i outlined, MINUS or a NOT IN. I can see that we are looking at atleast 2 FTS (or a Index scan depending on whether there is one with year as leading col). Would yours generate a better plan? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

There are atleast 2 ways and possibly many other alternatives.

First uses the MINUS operator

```
SELECT name
  FROM table1
 WHERE year = 2009
MINUS
SELECT name
  FROM table1
 WHERE year = 2010
```

You could also use a NOT IN to do the same thing

```
SELECT name
  FROM table1
 WHERE year = 2009
       AND name NOT IN (SELECT name
                          FROM table1
                         WHERE year = 2010)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like both the other answers (except for the `NOT IN` alternative, which tends to be slow). Another approach is to left join the "2009" names to the "after 2009" names and check for null "after 2009" names:

```
SELECT table1.name
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT name
  FROM table1
  WHERE year > 2009
) After2009 ON table1.name = After2009.name
WHERE table1.year = 2009
  AND After2009.name IS NULL
```

When joining two tables this approach tends to be pretty fast. I'm not sure if that holds true when self-joining.

This answer is also "general", by which I mean it will work - as Gordon's does - in most other databases.